# modulo inside stash list

Tags: stash, conditionals, list

I have a stash list for displaying entries.
In general a row has 3 columns, but I also want to break with rows of 2 columns.

layout looks like:

30%|30%|30%
30%|30%|30%
50%|50%
30%|30%|30%
30%|30%|30%
50%|50%
30%|30%|30%
30%|30%|30%
50%|50%

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="dataEntries" prefix="archiveEntriesHomeList" require_prefix="no"}  
    {if archiveEntriesHomeList:count % 7 == 0} DO 50% column
    {if:elseif archiveEntriesHomeList:count % 8 == 0} DO 50% column
    {if:else} DO 30% column {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

but this will not work, since 50% columns should displayed when count is:

7 & 8
15 & 16
23 & 24
31 & 32
and so on...

any idea how to do implement this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part of the conditional test for modulus of the next number:

```
{if (count + 1) % 8 == 0 }
```

So you end up with something like:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="test"}  
    {if (count + 1) % 8 == 0 } {count} DO 50% column<br>
    {if:elseif count % 8 == 0} {count} DO 50% column<br>
    {if:else} {count} DO 30% column<br> {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: you are the man, thx!